# Applying multi processing to different versions f multi processing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiprocessing, format

I want to run all the `formatting` functions synchronously with the `multiprocessing` function. How would I be able to add this function so it runs synchronously with the multi processing functions below I tried doing it however it doesn't work. Essentially, I want to run `formating(Numbers, limit1)`, `formating(Numbers, limit2)` and `formating(Numbers, limit3)` all at once.

Code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
def formating(a, b):
    # Formating goes here
    x = np.sort(b);
    # digitize
    l = np.digitize(a, x)
    # output:
    result = np.bincount(l, weights=a)
    return result

Numbers = np.array([3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10,20])
limit1 = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12, 15])
limit2 = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12])
limit3 = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12, 15, 22])
formating(Numbers, limit1)
formating(Numbers, limit2)
formating(Numbers, limit3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can show you how to do it, but you will be very unhappy with the results. There are two issues. The first issue is that there is a certain amount of overhead in creating a process pool and in passing arguments to your worker function and getting the return values back because the worker function "lives" in a different address space and arguments and return values must be "pickled" and "unpickled" for transmission. Therefore, the worker function, `formating` in your case, needs to be non-trivial to make the overhead incurred worthwhile. Second, your worker function uses `numpy`, which itself depending on what it is doing sometimes uses multiprocessing internally for some of its method calls. Using your own multiprocessing on top of it is not going to buy you anything. The fact that the worker function is short and `numpy` methods are written in the C language and execute quickly, this is an example of a rather trivial worker function.

The following is a benchmark of making the 3 `formating` calls in a loop that is iterated 100 times and timing the elapsed time and then repeating the same thing using a multiprocessing pool of size 3 with method `Pool.map` and then again using method `Pool.apply_async` (for this example, I expect the last two multiprocessing cases to be more or less the same in running time):

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
from functools import partial
import time

def formating(a, b):
    # Formating goes here
    x = np.sort(b);
    # digitize
    l = np.digitize(a, x)
    # output:
    result = np.bincount(l, weights=a)
    return result

# needed for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Numbers = np.array([3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10,20])
    limit1 = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12, 15])
    limit2 = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12])
    limit3 = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12, 15, 22])

    TRIALS = 100

    # non-multiprocessing:
    t = time.time()
    for _ in range(TRIALS):
        result1 = formating(Numbers, limit1)
        result2 = formating(Numbers, limit2)
        result3 = formating(Numbers, limit3)
    elapsed = time.time() - t
    print(result1, result2, result3, elapsed)

    # multiprocessing version 1 (using method map):
    # since first argument to formating is always the same:
    worker = partial(formating, Numbers)
    t = time.time()
    for _ in range(TRIALS):
        with mp.Pool(3) as pool:
            result1, result2, result3 = pool.map(worker, [limit1, limit2, limit3])
    elapsed = time.time() - t
    print(result1, result2, result3, elapsed)

    # multiprocessing version 2 (using method apply_async)
    t = time.time()
    for _ in range(TRIALS):
        with mp.Pool(3) as pool:
            results = [pool.apply_async(formating, args=(Numbers, limit)) for limit in [limit1, limit2, limit3]]
            result1, result2, result3 = [result.get() for result in results]
    elapsed = time.time() - t
    print(result1, result2, result3, elapsed)
```

Prints:

```
[ 0.  0.  7. 30.  0. 20.] [ 0.  0.  7. 30. 20.] [ 0.  0.  7. 30.  0. 20.] 0.00299835205078125
[ 0.  0.  7. 30.  0. 20.] [ 0.  0.  7. 30. 20.] [ 0.  0.  7. 30.  0. 20.] 27.002381324768066
[ 0.  0.  7. 30.  0. 20.] [ 0.  0.  7. 30. 20.] [ 0.  0.  7. 30.  0. 20.] 27.023000240325928
```

**Results**

The multiprocessing version only runs about 9000 times more slowly (and there is no difference between using `map` and `apply_async`).

If I take out the overhead of creating the pool from the benchmark, things improve greatly:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
from functools import partial
import time

def formating(a, b):
    # Formating goes here
    x = np.sort(b);
    # digitize
    l = np.digitize(a, x)
    # output:
    result = np.bincount(l, weights=a)
    return result

# needed for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Numbers = np.array([3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10,20])
    limit1 = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12, 15])
    limit2 = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12])
    limit3 = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12, 15, 22])

    TRIALS = 100

    # multiprocessing version 1 (using method map):
    # since first argument to formating is always the same:
    worker = partial(formating, Numbers)
    with mp.Pool(3) as pool:
        t = time.time()
        for _ in range(TRIALS):
            result1, result2, result3 = pool.map(worker, [limit1, limit2, limit3])
        elapsed = time.time() - t
    print(result1, result2, result3, elapsed)
```

Prints:

```
[ 0.  0.  7. 30.  0. 20.] [ 0.  0.  7. 30. 20.] [ 0.  0.  7. 30.  0. 20.] 0.32500314712524414
```

But it still takes .325 seconds compared with .003 seconds. This just shows you that the major overhead is in the pool creation -- but you nevertheless do have to create the pool and consider that overhead.

This is *how* you do it, **but don't for this case**.

Comment: I have a function that is way larger in scale than the `formatting` function, much like this function all the functions are numpy included. It takes about 600 ms to run for once but I am using a for loop which will runs about 500k times. Do you think i should use multi processing in this case?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply by the way I was a bit busy the past week. Thanks a lot for the sample code and detailed explanation. If I may ask the purpose of the `Trial` function?

Comment: To answer your first question first: Depending on what `numpy` functions you are using, you may not see any improvement because `numpy` uses multiprocessing itself internally for certain functions (I can't tell you which) and your using multiprocessing on top of that is self-defeating. But otherwise I would expect that you will see a great improvement if instead of looping 500K times you are now submitting 500K tasks. Try to use `map`, `starmap`, or `imap` (with an explicit *chunksize* argument) if you can where tasks will be submitted in suitably large chunks and use the default pool size.

Comment: What `Trial` function? There is a `TRIALS` constant to run a number of iterations of each code just to get longer timings for comparison.